# Как вызвать экран настроек Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как вызвать экран настроек Preference?

Код вызова:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {//Обработка нажатий сохранения, настройки и запуска файла.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    Preferences.class);
            startActivity(settingsActivity);
            return true;
```

Код SettingActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // загружаем предпочтения из ресурсов
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

КОД ОШИБКИ:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.blocnot, PID: 1835
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.blocnot/java.util.prefs.Preferences}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
                  at com.example.blocnot.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:44)
                  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2882)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:406)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:667)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3845)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3617)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.onTouchEvent(ListViewCompat.java:120)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:1682)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:57
```

Application terminated.

Comment: Строка `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` Вам о чем-нибудь говорит? Активити `Preferences` прописана в `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Как правильно объявить? Впервые с этим работаю.

Comment: Открываете файл `AndroidManifest.xml`, добавляете внутрь `application` строку `<activity android:name=".Preferences">`.

Comment: @MPrect, а почему вы запускаете Preferences активити, а сами настроки отображаете в SettingActivity?

Comment: Поправил. Просто эксперементировал из за того, что не мог найти решения.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте добавить Вашу `activity` в `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Для этого, открываете файл `AndroidManifest.xml` и добавляете внутрь тега `application` следующую строку:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName">
```

где `YourActivityName` – название Вашей `activity`.

Так же, Вы можете создавать новые `activity` с помощью мастера создания `activity`:

**File** – **New** – **Activity**

В этом случае, информация о создаваемой `activity` будет добавлена в `AndroidManifest.xml` автоматически.